# How do I decode a URL and get the query string as a HashMap?

Tags: rust, query-string, parse-url

I have a URL like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3
```

I parsed it with `hyper::Url::parse` and fetch the query string:

```
let parsed_url = hyper::Url::parse(&u).unwrap();
let query_string = parsed_url.query();
```

But it gives me the query as a string. I want to get the query string as `HashMap`. something like this:

```
// some code to convert query string to HashMap
hash_query.get(&"a"); // eq to 1
hash_query.get(&"b"); // eq to 2
```

Comment: Should the input be `http://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3` instead? It's not a valid URL when it's encoded like that.

Comment: [`percent_decode`](https://docs.rs/percent-encoding/2.1.0/percent_encoding/fn.percent_decode.html) lib works for fully encoded URLs like Saeed's:  `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few steps involved:

- The [`.query_pairs()`](https://docs.rs/url/1.4.0/url/struct.Url.html#method.query_pairs) method will give you an iterator over pairs of `Cow<str>`.
- Calling [`.into_owned()`](https://docs.rs/url/1.4.0/url/form_urlencoded/struct.Parse.html#method.into_owned) on that will give you an iterator over `String` pairs instead.
- This is an iterator of `(String, String)`, which is exactly the right shape to [`.collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) into a `HashMap<String, String>`.

Putting it together:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
let parsed_url = Url::parse("http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3").unwrap();
let hash_query: HashMap<_, _> = parsed_url.query_pairs().into_owned().collect();
assert_eq!(hash_query.get("a"), "1");
```

Note that you need a type annotation on the `hash_query`—since `.collect()` is overloaded, you have to tell the compiler which collection type you want.

If you need to handle repeated or duplicate keys, try the [`multimap`](https://docs.rs/multimap/0.8.3/multimap/) crate:

```
use multimap::MultiMap;
let parsed_url = Url::parse("http://example.com/?a=1&a=2&a=3").unwrap();
let hash_query: MultiMap<_, _> = parsed_url.query_pairs().into_owned().collect();
assert_eq!(hash_query.get_vec("a"), Some(&vec!["1", "2", "3"]));
```

Comment: Be warned that this overwrites duplicate keys. Many web frameworks take advantage of the fact that you can submit the same key multiple times.

Comment: Note that if you just have a query string, not a full URL, then you can use [`url::form_urlencoded::parse()`](https://docs.rs/url/1.4.0/url/form_urlencoded/fn.parse.html) instead.

Comment: Where is the ``HashMap`` type coming from? Edit: Neverming, it's ``::std::collections::HashMap``.

Comment: is there a way to parse repeated/duplicated keys as an array?

Comment: @tworec to preserve repeated keys, change the `HashMap<_, _>` to `Vec<_>`

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is good, but I feel that this is something that should be more
straightforward, so I wrapped it in a function:

```
use {
   std::collections::HashMap,
   url::Url
};

fn query(u: Url) -> HashMap<String, String> {
   u.query_pairs().into_owned().collect()
}

fn main() -> Result<(), url::ParseError> {
   let u = Url::parse("http://stackoverflow.com?month=May&day=Friday")?;
   let q = query(u);
   println!("{:?}", q);
   Ok(())
}
```

Alternatively, I found another crate that does this for you:

```
use auris::URI;

fn main() -> Result<(), auris::ParseError> {
   let s = "http://stackoverflow.com?month=May&day=Friday";
   let u: URI<String> = s.parse()?;
   println!("{:?}", u.qs); // Some({"month": "May", "day": "Friday"})
   Ok(())
}
```

https://docs.rs/auris

Comment: Regarding `auris`, I'm a bit suspicious of a crate that has no repository and no dependents. It's probably fine but I'd rather stick with the more reputable package.

Comment: @LambdaFairy here is the repo: https://github.com/bluemoon/auris

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for parsing an already-decoded query string from `&str` into `HashMap<String, String>` using *only* the Rust standard library, with no external crates required:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn parse_query(query: &str) -> HashMap<String, String> {
    query
        .split('&')
        .filter_map(|s| {
            s.split_once('=')
                .and_then(|t| Some((t.0.to_owned(), t.1.to_owned())))
        })
        .collect()
}
```